# What is the procedure to appeal an FAA DPE who conducts exams in a manner that conflicts with certification standards?

Tags: faa, checkride, designated-examiner

Does the FAA have a formal process to allow applicants and instructors to appeal a DPE who does not conduct pilot examinations in a manner consistent with the ACS/PTS guidelines?

If yes, how does the process work?

Comment: Contact your local FSDO. Keep in mind that the aviation community is very tightly knit. Have all of your evidence ready when you approach the FSDO. If it becomes a matter of he-said she-said the DPE will likely face no action. If you can prove the DPE did something wrong you will likely destroy the DPE's reputation and end their career.

Comment: Based on the little bit of time I spend researching this myself, it appears as if the FAA has some sort of complaint hotline.